# Error messages while creating data frames in R

Tags: r

I don't really know where to start. I've been working with the Fitabase datasets located on Kaggle. I've been working with these datasets for weeks now to do exploratory analysis. I've been having lots of problems. I'll try to be as descriptive as possible.

I'm getting multiple `could not find function "read_csv"` error messages after creating my data frames. The weird thing is, though I get these error messages, the data frames exist.

The second error message that I receive tells me that the `glimpse()` function doesn't exist. However, I am able to use the `str()` function.

Third, I get an error for `%>%` , but it still makes the changes I tell it to make, meaning, this error doesn't stop the changes from being made to the data frame.

So the next thing is probably the most strange. And that's when I'm working with my datetime data. I've been having huge problems working with datetime data in R. I noticed that R asks me to restart while it's trying to install and load the packages that I'm working with.

Before I'd tell it not to restart, and all of the aforementioned issues were not happening. `read_csv()` worked, `glimpse()` worked, and `%>%` worked, however, when I tried to parse through my datetime data, RStudio would crash, or my entire computer would crash. After allowing R to restart while installing and loading packages, that's when I started getting all of these error messages when running my code, even though most of the code results in intact data frames. But now I can parse through datetime data, however I still get error messages, and the data doesn't parse correctly. There is missing data. Does anyone have any idea why these things are happening? Any insight would be very much appreciated.

[read_csv error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaIFY.png)

[readr install success proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKQMc.png)

[Error message for pipe and glimpse functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUvFr.png)

[Intact data frame in spite of pipe function error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlEx7.png)

Comment: Welcome. Please share your code and error message by pasting them as plain text rather than as images. Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you need to install and load ``tidyverse``.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response user438383. I do have tidyverse installed and loaded. It's the first package that I installed.

Comment: Can you add a reproducible example? I.e.: paste the code here

Comment: I can work on creating a reproducible example, but I just wanted to get this question out there. I'm new to this, so I'm currently unsure of how to create a reproducible example.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Nini. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question.

Comment: I'm not sure how to provide a smaller dataset and still get my question answered. Can I provide access to the datasets I'm working with and my code as is?

Comment: We can only speculate because you haven't shared the data or code you're working with (enough of each to reproduce your issue). But based on what you've shared it appears (1) you're having an issue loading packages correctly. For instance, `glimpse()` and `%>%` require loading packages while `str()` is available in base. (2) You may get an error message from `read_csv`, but see those data (or settings/etc) in your environment because RStudio loads them from a previous session from `.Rdata` and `.Renvrion` files. I'd recommend starting with a fresh session/script/directory to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Skaqqs. I just realized this morning that these data frames are from another session after changing the names of the df's and trying to recreate them. So now I realize that it's an internal issue with loading the packages. Could you point me in the direction of finding out how to troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question. Like Skaqqs said, RStudio encountered a problem with the way the packages were loading. I found a very helpful blog post that I will link to that fixed the problem.

Run the install packages command first, and then input whatever packages you're working with in the `p_load` function

```
install.packages("pacman")

pacman::p_load(ggplot2, tidyr, dplyr)
```

Link to blog post: https://statsandr.com/blog/an-efficient-way-to-install-and-load-r-packages/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).